# how to set initial conditions when solving recursive equation with tables

Tags: list-manipulation

I am solving a recursive expression with `ParallelTable`. Here is a MWE showing how I do it, and how I set the initial condition:

```
SetSharedVariable[vals]
t[n_] := t[n - 1]*i*NIntegrate[Exp[-i*x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];

t[0] = 1;

vals = ParallelTable[{i, t[3]}, {i, 1, 500}];
```

The expression `t` depends on `i` implicitly. Now I want to make this dependency explicit, as shown here (note, it is **not** a functioning example!):

```
SetSharedVariable[vals]
t[d_, n_] := 
  t[n - 1]*d*NIntegrate[Exp[-d*x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];

(* WHAT TO DO WITH THIS, THE INITIAL CONDITION? *)
t[i, 0] = 1;

vals = ParallelTable[{i, t[i, 3]}, {i, 1, 500}];
```

My concern is regarding the initial condition. When I am dealing with `tables`, is there an easy way to implement initial conditions, or do I have to use a `For`-loop for that (where `i` is the variable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Clear[t]
SetSharedVariable[vals]
t[d_, n_] := 
   t[d, n - 1]*d*NIntegrate[Exp[-d*x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]; (*missing d*)

t[_, 0] := 1;


vals = ParallelTable[{i, t[i, 3]}, {i, 1, 500}]
```

To check:

```
Table[t[i, 0], {i, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```